# Discord.jsでbotを作成していてエラーが出る

Tags: discord

Discordのmusicbotを以下の動画を見ながらやっていたんですが、Botは起動するのに音楽を再生してくれません。

[MAKE YOUR OWN DISCORD.JS MUSIC BOT! - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VBj_UlaG_Ig&t=367s)

**エラー:**

[image: これがエラー]

**Discord画面:**

[image: Discord画面]

Comment: ログイン情報などは伏せたままで構わないので、ソースコードは画像ではなく文字のまま質問文に貼り付けてみてください (質問はあとからでも編集できます)。

Comment: 提示されているソースのスクリーンショット上では、`const prefix = '?';`と`message.content.slice(Prefix.length)`で、`prefix`の最初を大文字と小文字で間違えているようですが。ターミナル上のエラーメッセージも、`ReferenceError: Prefix is not defined`で、大文字で始まる`Prefix`という変数は定義されていない、となっています。

Comment: すみません。いろいろいじったんですがとうとうBOTがログインしてコマンドを実行するとエラーも出なくなりました(音楽は流れません

Comment: その動画ではなくて、この辺のソースもありそうな動画 [Create a Discord.JS music bot!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LeH2R-UIx0s&ab_channel=Salvage_Dev), [Milo123459/salvage-music](https://github.com/Milo123459/salvage-music) とか、テキスト記事 [How to create a music bot using Discord.js](https://gabrieltanner.org/blog/dicord-music-bot), [TannerGabriel/discord-bot](https://github.com/TannerGabriel/discord-bot) とか、[ZerioDev/Music-bot](https://github.com/ZerioDev/Music-bot), [eritislami/evobot](https://github.com/eritislami/evobot), [discord.js-musicbot-v2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord.js-musicbot-v2) とか動いてそうなものを改造するとか。

Comment: 分かりましたやってみます